# Double integral in polar coordinates $\int _{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}^1\:\int _{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^1\:\frac{dydx}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Hello I've been trying to do this integral

$$\int _{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}^1\:\int _{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^1\:\frac{dydx}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

but with polar coordinates (since that's the question in my textbook)

First I calculated the intersection between x and y

$x=cos(\theta)=y=sin(\theta)$ therefore $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Now for the integral I calculated

$$\int _{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}^1\:\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{4}}\:\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2}}drd\theta $$

after solving this gave me

$$\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{\pi }{4\sqrt{2}}$$

The problem I have here is that my textbook says the answer should be $\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)-\frac{\pi}{4}$

Is my textbook wrong or did I make a mistake?

Comment: The limits of integration you have are wrong.

Comment: Are the bounds of the outer or inner integral wrong? Or both?

Comment: Both are wrong...?

Comment: Okay, thank you for letting me know.

Comment: Yes, both. Draw a picture of your domain $\frac{\sqrt2}2<x<1,\;\sqrt{1-x^2}<y<1.$

Comment: Yes I did, I don't know why I used y=x instead of y=1 thanks

Comment: That being said, I find it awful to compute in polar coordinates on such a domain. I hope your textbook doesn't really demand that.

Comment: Sadly they do demand that.. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though awkward using the polar coordinates, it can be done as follows

\begin{align}
&\int _{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}^1\:\int _{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^1\:\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dydx\\
=&\ \bigg( \int_0^{\pi/4}\int_1^{\sec\theta}+ \int_{\pi/4}^{\tan^{-1}\sqrt2}\int_{\frac{\sec \theta}{\sqrt2}}^{\csc\theta}
 \bigg)dr d\theta\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much